# Data not showing in jTable, no data appears in it

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using phpMyAdmin through xampp as my host, I can add data just fine but when I run the application it doesn't show any data. Could someone please check my code. I am new to programming in java so please bear with me.

```
public DefaultTableModel getmodel(){
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jtbl.getModel();
                model.setRowCount(0);
                show_data_in_jtable();
                return null;
}
public ArrayList<User> getuserList()
  {
       ArrayList<User> userList =  new ArrayList<User>();
        Connection Conn2 = m2.getConnection();
        String query = "select * from Student ";
        Statement st;
          ResultSet rs;

          try{
          st = Conn2.createStatement();
          rs = st.executeQuery(query);
          User user_var;

          while(rs.next())
                {
            user_var = new User(rs.getInt("id"),rs.getString("fname"),rs.getString("lname"),rs.getString("mname"),rs.getInt("age"),rs.getString("Gender"),rs.getString("course"));
            userList.add(user_var);
                }
          }
          catch (Exception error)
          {
              error.printStackTrace();
            }
          return userList;
    }
// display data on Jtable
public void show_data_in_jtable()
   {
   ArrayList<User> list = getuserList();
   DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)  jtbl.getModel();
    Object[] column = new Object[5];

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            {
               column  [0] = list.get(i).getId();
                   column [1] = list.get(i).getFirstName();
                      column [2] = list.get(i).getLastName();
                      column [3] = list.get(i).getLastName();
                         column [4] = list.get(i).getMiddleName();
                            column [5] = list.get(i).getGender();
                            column [6] = list.get(i).getCourse();
                         model.addRow(column);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your model to a Jtable?

If you did that what is result of getuserList() function? Did you debug your code?

Check this [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer to your question, as I think your problem stems from not adding the model correcting to the table, however I would encourage you to not use the DefaultTableModel.  Create your own model by extending AbstractTableModel, it will make your life easier in the long run:

```
 public class UserTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return 6;
}

public String getColumnName(int col) {
    switch (col) {
    case 0:
        return "ID";
    case 1:
        return "Last Name";
    case 2:
        return "First Name";
    case 3:
        return "Middle Name";
    case 4:
        return "Gender";
    case 5:
        return "Course";
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return users.size();
}

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users.clear();
    if (users != null) {
        this.users.addAll(users);
    }
    fireTableDataChanged();
}

public void addUser(User user) {
    users.add(user);
    fireTableRowsInserted(users.size() - 1, users.size() - 1);
}

public void removeUser(User user) {
    if (user != null) {
        users.removeIf(u -> u.getId().contentEquals(user.getId()));
    }
    fireTableDataChanged();
}
public void removeRow(int row) {
    if (row >= 0 && row < users.size()) {
        users.remove(row);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    if (row >= 0 && row < users.size() && col >= 0 && col < getColumnCount()) {
        User user = users.get(row);
        switch (col) {
        case 0:
            return user.getId();
        case 1:
            return user.getFirstName();
        case 2:
            return user.getLastName();
        case 3:
            return user.getMiddleName();
        case 4:
            return user.getGender();
        case 5:
            return user.getCourse();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```